# Chat with me link in Joomla 3.6 custom html module

Tags: javascript, joomla, joomla-module, joomla3.6

Is there a way to insert this code on a Joomla custom module and have it act like a button, instead of putting this on the header of the template?

```
{if isset($aUser.is_online) && $aUser.is_online && Phpfox::isModule('im') && Phpfox::getParam('im.enable_im_in_footer_bar') && $aUser.is_friend == 1}
            <li> 
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="jqcc.cometchat.chatWith('{$aUser.user_id}');">{img theme='module/chat.png' class='v_middle'} {phrase var='profile.instant_chat'}</a></li>    {/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can do that. What you need to do is add the above to a custom HTML module, and then create an override for the template of the custom HTML module that doesn't contain any divs (just has `echo ($module->content);`).

Comment: Hi, thx for your reply but you got me lost now, and to achieve this override in custom css?